# solidity - Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable requested

Tags: typeerror

I am trying to give address as payable but I am getting error at msg.sender and address(_author).transfer(msg.value) . it was showing like Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address to address payable requested. i tried many ways to solve every time i replace the same error. before adding payable to author it was fine, but when added payable to author then it started getting error. In both, msg.sender and msg.value

---

```
  pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.9.0;
    
    contract SocialNetwork {
        string public name;
        uint public postCount = 0;
        mapping(uint => Post) public posts;
    
    
        struct Post {
            uint id;
            string content;
            uint tipAmount;
            address payable author;
        }
    
        event PostCreated(
            uint id,
            string content,
            uint tipAmount,
            address payable author
        );
    
        event PostTipped(
            uint id,
            string content,
            uint tipAmount,
            address payable author
        );
    
        constructor() public {
            name = "Yash university Social Network";
        }
    
        function createPost(string memory _content) public {
            //REquire Valid content
            require(bytes(_content).length > 0);
            
            // InCREMENT the post count
            postCount ++;
            // Create the post
            posts[postCount] = Post(postCount, _content, 0, msg.sender);
            // Trigger event 
            emit PostCreated(postCount, _content, 0, msg.sender);
    
        }
    
        function tipPost(uint _id) public payable {
    
            //fetch the post
            Post memory _post = posts[_id];
            //fetch the author
            address payable _author = _post.author;
            //pay the author
            address(_author).transfer(msg.value);
            //increment the tip post
            _post.tipAmount = _post.tipAmount + msg.value;
            //update the post
            posts[_id] = _post;
            //Trigger an event
            emit PostTipped(postCount, _post.content, _post.tipAmount, _author); 
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues in your code:

1- in the `Post` struct, you defined address as payable:

```
  struct Post {
        uint id;
        string content;
        uint tipAmount;
        address payable author;
    }
```

But when you are creating a post, you are passing `msg.sender` which has `address` type. Before v0.8.0 `msg.sender` was payable but since than you have to cast it as `payable(msgs.sender)`. it should be:

```
function createPost(string memory _content) public {
            require(bytes(_content).length > 0);
            postCount ++;
            posts[postCount] = Post(postCount, _content, 0, payable(msg.sender)); 
            emit PostCreated(postCount, _content, 0, payable(msg.sender));
        }
```

2- in `tipPost` function you are getting payable address

```
address payable _author = _post.author;
```

but then you are casting it with `address`. In solidity `address` and `payable address` are two different things. `send` and `transfer` are only available to the `payable address` type. You dont need this:

```
   address(_author).transfer(msg.value);
```

instead just

```
   _author.transfer(msg.value);
```